# Special Character '&' in XPATH Query

Tags: xpath, ampersand

Using Windows 7 and Creating a scheduled task based on a trigger.
The following line is resulting in "The event log query specified is invalid"
**[EventData[Data[@Name='Network Client'] and (Data="C:\Program Files (x86)\AT&T Network Client\NetVC.exe")]]**

I have uncovered the cause to be the ampersand in the path name "AT&T"
If I remove the ampersand then the query is understandable, but of course the path name then becomes invalid.
Is there some method where the ampersand special char can used in this situation?

Comment: Use `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Comment: Thx Alexander.  "C:\Program Files (x86)\AT&amp;T Network Client\NetVC.exe")]] works now.

Comment: Note that XPath itself allows an unescaped ampersand in an string literal. The failure is probably because the XPath expression appears in some XML file, and XML requires ampersand to be escaped.