# Remove a specific string inside a string in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I have the following strings:

```
U########## 

B##########

############ (Last two digits are term indicator)

############ (Last two digits are term indicator)

OLF####### or OLTD####### or OLF######### (Last two digits are the term indicator) or OLTD######### (Last two digits are term indicator) or 

OICF######### (Last two digits are term indicator) 09-##########-## (Last two digits are the term indicator)

OL######## or OLT####### or OL######### (Last two digits are the term indicator) or OLT######### (Last two digits are the term indicator) or OIC########## (Last two digits are the term indicator)

UDC_#######_##_01 or  UDV_#######_##_01 or UWD_#######_##_01 (11th & 12th digits are the term indicator)
```

My objective is to remove the mid strings or end strings that are enclosed in parenthesis. ie. (Last two digits are term indicator).

I am looking for a formula or vb code that will help me to remove these strings that are enclosed in paranthesis. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would need TEXTJOIN and FILTERXML, both are newer formula and may not be available in all versions:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&","|"),"(","</b>"),")","<b>")&"</b></a>","//b[string-length(.)>0]")),"|","&"))
```

[image]

---

As per @JvdV we can shorten it using `&amp;`

```
=TRIM(TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&","&amp;"),"(","</b>"),")","<b>")&"</b></a>","//b[string-length(.)>0]")))
```

Comment: I tried this and it works very stange. I entered the formula on the first cell (B2) and entered it. and then when I double click on the lower right corner to copy the formula, the same string (ie. if first cell A2 contains ####&&######, then that is the same value on other cells B2:B250 where the formula is copied) is repeated on the other cells. When I go to the next cell (ie. B3) and inspect the formula and hit enter, then i am getting the correct string (ie. if A3 contains ####&_######, then B3 also contains ####&_######....before that B3 was  ####&&######)

Comment: You may have your calcs not set to automatic.  Try hitting F9.

Comment: Nice Scott! + =)

Comment: @JvdV took me a good 20 minutes to figure out that FILTERXML does not like `&`.

Comment: Yeah if you ever need to use it somehow in a string-check, use `&amp;` [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416042/9758194). Btw. you can get the same result with `"//b[node()]"`. The times `FILTERXML` is helpfull...=)